# How to find rank of a matrix with given condition?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $P = \{p_{ij}\}$ be a $50 \times 50$ matrix, where $p_{ij} = \min(i,j) ; \, i,j=1, 2, \ldots, 50$. Then what would be the rank of $P$?

I am aware that I can reduce the given matrix into Echelon form to find the rank. But the problem is how to construct a matrix from $P = \{p_{ij}\}$ with given condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of the matrix $P$ will be

\begin{align}
P & = \begin{bmatrix}
i_{1}j_{1} & i_{1}j_{2} & \ldots & i_{1}j_{50} \\
i_{2}j_{1} & i_{2}j_{2} & \ldots & i_{2}j_{50} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
i_{50}j_{1} & i_{50}j_{2} & \ldots & i_{50}j_{50} 
\end{bmatrix} \\
& = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \ldots & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 &\ldots & 2 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 3 & \ldots & 3 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \ldots & 4 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \ldots & 50
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Now, this can easily be proved that all the rows or columns are linearly independent.

Comment: ..Got it. Thankyou.

Comment: Please accept the answer if you're satisfied! @demon